# What is semantic in Database?

Tags: database, semantics, semantic-web

Can anyone help me what does **semantic** means in following sentence?

`We use semantic of data record for ...`

Comment: Can you provide additional data? Maybe the rest of the sentence

Comment: @MenelaosVergis for improving query result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not just the data is seen as a bunch of text but is looked as a representation of objects and properties interlinking with other objects and properties, which gives more information about the data.